# Child process file descriptors without customFds

Tags: node.js, yeoman, child-process

I see that [`customFds`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) is deprecated/removed from `child_process.spawn`.  Is there any alternative to directly using a process' file descriptors for a child process?

Specifically, I'm running

```
var yo = spawn("yo", args, {                                           
    customFds: [0,1,2]                                                   
});
```

This works perfectly even in node 0.10.28, but I want the code to be future proof of course.

```
var yo = spawn("yo", args);
process.stdin.pipe(yo);
yo.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
yo.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
yo.on("close", function (code) {
    process.exit(code);
});
```

The above also works but there are two big problems:

1. Colors are not output to the terminal (probably stripped by the piping)
2. The process does not actually exit / the `close` event seemingly doesn't fire

What can I do to properly pass process input/output to a child process in node?

Comment: What are you trying to do with Yeoman there?

Comment: @EddieMongeJr just use a Yeoman generator

Comment: Have you read the getting started guide to writing a generator?

Comment: @EddieMongeJr this is not a generator, this is a wrapper that *calls* a generator